# Squid: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I want to set up a **public HTTP proxy** using **Squid**. I installed it successfully on Ubuntu 14.04 and just added two lines in `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 3120 transparent
```

However trying to `curl MY_SERVER_IP_HERE:3120 ya.ru`, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. If don't set `transparent` directive in `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`, I get `The requested URL could not be retrieved` error in my browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting your proxy via curl not telling curl to use the proxy.. Try this

```
http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:3120/ curl http://ya.ru
```

You can make it perminate for the session by

```
export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server:3120/
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, one can run two kinds of (HTTP) proxies:

- Normal: you need to configure each client (i.e. browsers) for using
  it.
- Transparent: Don't demand configuration, the hosts' traffic is
  sent to the proxy by their default gateway (using firewall rules). AFAIK, it is used on local networks.

As you can't control other people network settings, you should remove the **transparent** keyword from the **http_port** line, and tell your programs what proxy they should use. For most Linux command line programs, you'll use three environment vars: http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy (for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP protocols respectivelly).

Examples:

```
export http_proxy="http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE:3120"
export https_proxy="http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE:3120"
export ftp_proxy="http://MY_SERVER_IP_HERE:3120"
curl http://ya.ru
```